# c# datagridview entity framework не обновляются данные

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

datagridview не обновляется после изменения данных в БД. Как заставить его обновлять данные?

```
public void RefreshDGV()
{
    dgv.DataSource = context.Users.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Сперва `DataSource = null;`

Comment: Так пробовал уже. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov там же каждый раз новый список, нет смысла через `null`

Answer (score 0):

Надо было каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр объекта контекст. Сколько же я с этим мучался...

```
public void RefreshDGV()
    {
    **using(MyOscarContext context = new())**
         {
          gvULD.DataSource = context.Ulds.Where(u => u.Id > 0).ToList();
         }
    }
```